# Add new column in product table while placing order from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I want to add a custom column in the product table that is displayed while placing order from magento admin panel .

[image: I want something similar as shown in image]

A help will be appreciated

Comment: You need to override the admin grid controller for product

Comment: This table has js code that works with it - column count and their order matter there. If you add a column you will have to override a lot of core functionality

Comment: Are you attempting to DISPLAY a field / attribute that already exists for Products in Magento or are you trying to ADD a field that DOESN'T exist and then DISPLAY it here on the on the `Sales > Order > Create New Order` Admin View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a field in database table "sales_flat_order_item" like "statetax"
[image]

In your module config file.
add this code

```
<events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <test_taxgenerate_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Test_Taxgenerate_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setorderstatetax</method>
                </test_taxgenerate_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
```

And make observer file.

```
class Test_Taxgenerate_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object{
public function setorderstatetax(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteitem) {
       $quotetax[$i]['statetax'] = $quoteitem->getStatetax();
       $i++;
    }
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $j=0;
    foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
        $item->setStatetax($quotetax[$j]['statetax']);
        $item->save();
        $j++;
    }
}
```

}